# Applying for Schengen visa with an itinerary that is on hold

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Buying a ticket before having a Visa is risky. American Airlines allows holding a ticket for 24 hours for free, and sends an email with

> Thank you for making your travel arrangements on aa.com! Your requested itinerary is now ON HOLD. Details below.

Can I print the email and show it at the consulate for Schengen visa application?

I live in the US if this is relevant.

Comment: What consulate is it specifically if I may ask? Some have more or less strict requirements when it comes to flights

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't explicitly insufficient, it may lead to a refusal of your visa. The consular officer who will examine your application may check the reservation to see if it is valid.

Where you run into an issue is that the officer will most likely not check your flight details within 24h from whenever you made the reservation.

I'd recommend purchasing a fully refundable ticket (it is more costly but can obviously be refunded after your visa is issued). This is what I did for mine a couple of months back, except I just decided to use the flight I had booked anyway.

Comment: thanks, may I ask which airlines allow you to buy a fully refundable ticket?

Comment: Aeroflot economy flex ticket is what I used